# How to pass HashMap object from one method to another method in same Spring MVC controller class

Tags: java, spring

I have two services(methods) in a Spring MVC controller class.Now i want to move Map Object from one method to another method with values.

```
   public class Controller{

   @RequestMapping(value="/reg", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView loginData(@ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginBean 
    loginBean,ModelMap model) throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        //Here i have map object with values.
    }

   @RequestMapping(value="/update",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView updateForm(@ModelAttribute("frontBean")FrontBean 
   frontBean,ModelMap model)
   {
     //here i want to Map Object for update the values
   }
  }
```

is there any way to do like this 
please give solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Problem solved, here i have create global HashMap object in a controller class then i read Map object where i want.

Comment: You should provide your answer in the answers section. By doing that, others will benefit from your solution

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Using HttpSession.
You can use ***HttpSession*** to store your object. See the below example

```
public class Controller{

   @RequestMapping(value="/reg", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView loginData(@ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginBean 
    loginBean,ModelMap model) throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        Map map = new HashMap();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("myMapObject", map);
    }

   @RequestMapping(value="/update",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView updateForm(@ModelAttribute("frontBean")FrontBean 
   frontBean,ModelMap model)
   {
     HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
     session.getAttribute("myMapObject", map);
     session.removeAttribute("myMapObject");
   }
  }
```

---

**Method 2:** Using ***FlashAttribute***. It provides a way to store those attributes that are required to be shown on the next page at a redirect on a Post/Redirect/Get.

```
public class Controller{

   @RequestMapping(value="/reg", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView loginData(@ModelAttribute("loginBean")LoginBean 
    loginBean,ModelMap model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrib) throws IOException, ParseException
    {
        Map map = new HashMap();
        redirectAttrib.addAttribute("myMap", map);
        return "redirect:/update";
    }

   @RequestMapping(value="/update",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView updateForm(@ModelAttribute("frontBean")FrontBean 
   frontBean,@ModelAttribute("myMap")Map myMap,ModelMap model)
   {
  //Use myMap object accordingly.
   }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try redirect method.from reg to update with the parameter